# runtime 1004 error when running vba code for second time

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have written a small module to protect all the worksheets of my workbook and to protect certain ranges in certain sheets.

The code runs smoothly the first time around, but when trying to run it for a second time I get a runtime 1004 error "Application-defined or object-defined error"

I think I might have found some explanation on the following page:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178510
But I just can't figure it out..

Could somebody please give me a hand ?

My code is below.

Depending on what sheet gets protected first, it is either this line

```
WS.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:=titlef _
        , Range:=WS.Range("L:R"), Password:="pw2"
```

or the following line that throws the erorr

```
WS.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:=titlec _
        , Range:=WS.Range("N:T"), Password:="pw3"

Sub Protect()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim pWord As String
pWord = "pw1"

Dim aer As AllowEditRange
For Each WS In Worksheets
    WS.Unprotect pWord
For Each aer In WS.Protection.AllowEditRanges
    aer.Delete
Next aer
Next WS

Dim counterf As Integer
Dim counterc As Integer
counterf = 1
counterc = 1
Dim titlef As String
Dim titlec As String

For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    WS.Protect Password:=pWord, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True
    WS.EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions
    If InStr(UCase(WS.Name), "FORM") Then
        titlef = "Volumes form faits par poste" & counterf
        WS.Unprotect pWord
        WS.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:=titlef _
        , Range:=WS.Range("L:R"), Password:="pw2"
        WS.Protect pWord
        counterf = counterf + 1
    ElseIf InStr(UCase(WS.Name), "COND") Then
        titlec = "Volumes cond faits par poste" & counterc
        WS.Unprotect pWord
        WS.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:=titlec _
        , Range:=WS.Range("N:T"), Password:="pw3"
        WS.Protect pWord
        counterc = counterc + 1
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is the error being thrown on?

Comment: Put breakpoints and then let us know where exactly the error occurs

Comment: You're right, I forgot to mention the line that throws the error!
I will edit it in my original post!

Comment: I realize this is two years late so it may be entirely irrelevant, but you may be encountering an issue because you are adding the "AllowEditRange" while the sheet is unprotected.  In my experience, AERs can only be _added_ while the sheet is protected, and only _deleted_ while the sheet is Unprotected

Answer (score 0):

Based on the KB article you posted I think the problem is with `Worksheets` and/or `ActiveWorkbook`. Since you aren't specifically instantiating these objects Excel is providing you with a copy, essentially filling in the blanks. However this copy is what is sticking around. The code below creates two variables at the top and kills off those variables at the bottom. Then, instead of using `Worksheets` it uses `xlBook.Worksheets` and instead of `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` it uses `xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`.

```
Sub Protect()
    'Create an actual instance of the Excel Application and Workbook
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application 
    Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook

    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim pWord As String
    pWord = "pw1"

    Dim aer As AllowEditRange
    'Use the object's Worksheets instead of the automatic variable
    For Each WS In xlBook.Worksheets
        WS.Unprotect pWord
        For Each aer In WS.Protection.AllowEditRanges
            aer.Delete
        Next aer
    Next WS

    Dim counterf As Integer
    Dim counterc As Integer
    counterf = 1
    counterc = 1
    Dim titlef As String
    Dim titlec As String

    'Once again, use the application's property
    For Each WS In xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        WS.Protect Password:=pWord, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True
        WS.EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions
        If InStr(UCase(WS.Name), "FORM") Then
            titlef = "Volumes form faits par poste" & counterf
            WS.Unprotect pWord
            WS.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:=titlef _
            , Range:=WS.Range("L:R"), Password:="pw2"
            WS.Protect pWord
            counterf = counterf + 1
        ElseIf InStr(UCase(WS.Name), "COND") Then
            titlec = "Volumes cond faits par poste" & counterc
            WS.Unprotect pWord
            WS.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:=titlec _
            , Range:=WS.Range("N:T"), Password:="pw3"
            WS.Protect pWord
            counterc = counterc + 1
        End If
    Next

    'Clean up
    Set xlBook = Nothing
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Chris!
It is now throwing another erorr:
Run-time error 91: object variable or with block variable not set
on the following line
For Each WS In xlBook.Worksheets

Comment: Sorry, those variables need to be `Set`, too, but I don't know if that will solve your problem either.

Comment: Hi Cris,
I've managed to get past the run time error 91 by setting the variables accordingly:
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook
But it did not solve my problem :s

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I was just facing a similar issue in my code, and it seems to me that in order for the AlloEditRange.Delete function to work, the sheet itself must be active. So I believe that your initial nested For loop to delete all AllowEditRange objects doesn't do what you expect, it only works on the active sheet. Hence further down when you try to call AlloEditRanges.Add, this fails because there is one already there.

I guess you would need to activate each sheet before calling Delete in you for loop, thsough I don't like this as a "solution", more of a work around.